what triggers the MS virus/malware warning on a .py file?
I've been working with a .py file for a long time in a project, and it's not changed since it's created. It's only function is to create connection to mongodb.
Today when I try to open it in IDE, the MS virus/walware warning popped up and the file is removed from local git repo on laptop.
I kept sync this file from the git server, the OS keeps popping up the virus/malware warning and removing the file from my local git repo.
It was ok yesterday. A new virus/malware definition must have been added lately.

what is exactly the trigger for this warning?

The mechanics of virus detection are always kept secret - if the virus writers knew what triggered the detection, they'd take steps to avoid it.
